# This code not reload browser when file changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to reload browser when file change but I dont know how

```
var changing = require('changing');

var watcher = changing(
{
    interval: '0s'
});

watcher.add("/home/diegonode/Desktop/ExpressCart-master/routes/2.mk");

watcher.on('change', function (info) 
{
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(7777));

    io.sockets.emit('browserReload');

    console.log("info");
    console.error('An error occurred!');
});
```

please help me

Comment: You might see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20494778/2026740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use `gulp` task runner with [gulp-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload) plugin.